# How can I fix my issue creating a signed APK file?

Tags: android, publish

I would like to publish my app in the Google Play Store, but I am failing to create the required "app-release.apk". The error I get is the following:

Could not find org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824.
Searched in the following locations:

```
    file:/C:/Users/Albrecht/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
    file:/C:/Users/Albrecht/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar
    file:/C:/Users/Albrecht/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
    file:/C:/Users/Albrecht/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar
    file:/C:/Users/Albrecht/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
    file:/C:/Users/Albrecht/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar
    file:/C:/Users/Albrecht/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
    file:/C:/Users/Albrecht/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar
    https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
    https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar
    https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
    https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar
    https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
    https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar
    https://maven.google.com/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
    https://maven.google.com/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar
Required by:
    project :android > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.4 > com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:26.1.4
```

My build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {


    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'

    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "ShapeRecognisingGame"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.8'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.3'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.3'
        aiVersion = '1.8.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"

    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1"

        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"

    }
}
```

I have already checked out several other solutions for this error. However, none of them worked for me.

Comment: It simply means you have not installed studio with taking care and there are some necessary dependancies are unavailable thats why you are getting error... Uninstall properly... with each and every component and reinstall and let it download and install whatever are the requirements..!!

Comment: Could be more specific, please? I reinstalled Android Studio and payed close attention to any step of the Installation. However, I still get the same error What exactly should I pay Attention to ?

Comment: I am on AS 3.3 beta 4 and can confirm the issue, with the previous comment (you have not installed properly...) being false, not sure what was its intent.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the error as well and with LibGDX as well. Android Studio APK signing with LibGDX seems to be dependent on this library and unable to resolve it with default setup. After some laboring, the thing that seems to have helped is File - Settings - Build, Execution, Deployment - Gradle - Android Studio - Enable embedded Maven repository.

[image]

By the way, creating the new "bundle" instead of APK works out of the box without problems.

Comment: Thanks, that helped solve my issue where nothing else (removing mavenCentral/mavenLocal, reordering repositories) would.